# show image in specific position after onLongClick

Tags: android, android-layout, view, drawable

I am working on android 2.3.3 ++
How do i show an image in arbitrary position (x, y)?
I've implemented view.onLongClickListener:
        to_button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

```
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            showCircle(v, x, y);
            return true;
        }
```

Now i would like to show a circle (drawable) on position x, y.
How do i go about doing this in the most efficient way.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530350/android-press-longclicklistener-get-x-y-coordinates-ontouchlistener

Answer (score 3):

Implements `onTouch` method for you view, get the `x` and `y`, draw circle when `onLongClick` fired. Try this:

```
int x;
int y;
v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent ev) {
        if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            x = ev.getX();
            y = ev.getY();
        }
        return false;
    }
})
v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        showCircle(v, x, y);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @JonathanYarkoni, create your own View extends from `View`, implements `onDraw` method which can draw a circle/rect/drawable in a specified position, make a boolean for drawing or not drawing the circle, then every time `onLongClick` fire, turn the boolean to drawing, refresh your view by `v.invalidate()`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to draw a circle in Android, then you should take a look at this:
[Draw circle in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200171/draw-circle-in-android)